# How can I explain why when I run 2 multiple regressions, (1 with all my variables, the 2nd with all but one), the directions of some variables change?

Tags: multiple-regression

I ran two multiple regressions. The first with alm my variables. The second I removed one variable for which I had missing data for a lot of my cases. How can I explain why in the second multiple regression, an additional two variables become 'negative' in direction?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  This is a [faq](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+significant+not+faq).  If those posts don't help, look at [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=regression%20significant%20not%20&searchOn=3).  Or [this one about sign changes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+significant+change+sign).

Comment: See the first two pictures here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_paradox  and also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted_variable_bias

Comment: Can Simpson's Paradox and ommitted variable bias apply even when the coefficients are all insignificant?